# How to show just one newline using nl2br?

Tags: php, newline, nl2br

I am using `nl2br()` to convert `\n` characters to the `<br />` tag but I do not want more than one `<br />` tag at a time. For example, `Hello \n\n\n\n Everybody` should become `Hello <br /> Everybody`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most direct approach might be to first replace the multiple newlines with one using a simple regular expression:

```
nl2br(preg_replace("/\n+/", "\n", $input));
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. I have one more question. How can i allow 1 and 2 newline ?

Comment: If you want to preserve up to two `\n` characters, just put two of them in the regular expression and replacement:  `preg_replace("/\n\n+/", "\n\n", $input)`

Answer (score 3):

If you have php 5.2.4+ you can use preg_replace and the vertical whitespace character type `\v`

```
$str = preg_replace('/\v+/','<br>', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try replacing repeated newlines with single newlines using preg_replace() first, then using nl2br to convert to HTML 
 tags. `nl2br(preg_replace('/\n+/', '\n', $the_string))` should do the trick (untested).